# Using FromArgb for Int32[] value results in swapped Red and Blue values

Tags: powershell

I have this `Int32[]` value `14508153` which should be:

```
R             : 121
G             : 96
B             : 221
```

[image]

---

If I use:

```
[System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(14508153)
```

It returns:

```
R             : 221
G             : 96
B             : 121
A             : 0
IsKnownColor  : False
IsEmpty       : False
IsNamedColor  : False
IsSystemColor : False
Name          : dd6079
```

### Questions

1. How or why are those values swapped for `R` and `B` using that function?
2. Is there a built-in PowerShell method to convert them correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak to *why* the bytes need to be rearranged (see the bottom section for thoughts), but here's *how* you can do it:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$bytes = [System.BitConverter]::GetBytes(14508153)

[byte[]] $rearrangedBytes = $bytes[2], $bytes[1], $bytes[0], $bytes[3]

[System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(
  [System.BitConverter]::ToInt32($rearrangedBytes, 0)
)
```

See [`System.BitConverter.GetBytes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.BitConverter.GetBytes), [`System.BitConverter.ToInt32()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.BitConverter.ToInt32).

The above yields:

```
R             : 121
G             : 96
B             : 221
A             : 0
IsKnownColor  : False
IsEmpty       : False
IsNamedColor  : False
IsSystemColor : False
Name          : 7960dd
```

---

It appears that only *3* of the bytes in your `[int]` ([`System.Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Int32)) value are relevant, and that they are in *Big-Endian* order (see the Wikipedia article about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).

By contrast, [`System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb) expects *all 4* bytes to be relevant, in *Little-Endian* order.